# Card Reader Excel timetable

Tags: c#

I would like to prevent the looping and when i display the card. It should only display my name once and my friends name one. It is constant looping now.

This is what i have declared

```
int row = 2;
int count = 0;
int num = 0;
int name = 0;
bool=false;
if (CardReader.CANSnr.Equals("8009140003484246")) 
{
    scan = true;
    textBox1.Text = "Welcome Back";
    textBox2.Text = "Jonathan";
    DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
    string todaysDate = theDate.ToString("d");
    string todaysTime = theDate.ToString("T");
    //add Data to to cells
    excell_app.addData(row, 1, "Jonathan", "A1", "A1", "#,##0");
    excell_app.addData(row, 2, "1", "B1", "B1", "");
    excell_app.addData(row, 3, todaysDate, "C1", "C1", "#,##0");
    excell_app.addData(row, 4, todaysTime, "D1", "D1", "#,##0");
    row++;
}
```

Comment: I assume you've posted code for question as an answer - if it is the case - please delete answer, otherwise feel free to rollback my edit and update answer to actually contain answer. In either case avoid adding "thank you" text to the post (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove for guidance)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough information here to answer your question. You don't have a loop in the provided code, so any perceived looping must be happening at a higher level.

Otherwise, it looks like you have a var (`scan`) that you could use to prevent multiple scans from happening, if that's what you're after.

```
...
bool scan = false;
if (!scan && CardReader.CANSnr.Equals("8009140003484246")) 
{
    scan = true;
    ...
}
```